# Spring Social and Session Registry

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-social, session-management

I had an session management api, to logout certain users and so on backed by `SessionRegistry`, but now I have added Spring Social functionality and integrate it with current users. Unfortunately, using filter chain with `SocialAuthenticationFilter` do not integrate with Session Registry and I don't have information about sessions used by logged by OAuth users. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this or know better mechanism for logged users than `SessionRegistry`?

Comment: How do you solve your problem?

Comment: @PapaSmurf To be honest I didn't. Since I had asked this question, there were a lot of other problems and also I changed later my job and I haven't later an opportunity to use spring social again ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by adding the `SocialUserDetails` to the `SessionRegistry`.

So in my `SocialUserDetailsService` when I build (`loadUserByUserId`) the `SocialUserDetails` I do that:

```
this.sessionRegistry.registerNewSession(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), frontendUser);
```